# 3GS specific binary

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to build my binary just for 3GS as it contains NEON assembly code, my app only works on 3GS. When I upload the binary to iTunesConnect, it rejects the binary saying that it should be compatible with armv6 as well. Is there any build setting that I can use so that I have a binary which iTunesConnect happily accepts and which runs only on iPhone 3GS(armv7). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this post](http://monkeystylegames.com/?p=82) will help. Instead of picking both armv6 and armv7, specify armv7 to build a smaller binary.